# ubuntu 9.04 + enlightenment (e17 or e16)

Tags: ubuntu, enlightenment

I'd like to install the enlightenment window manager (preferably e16) onto my new ubuntu workstation.     However, the online guides seem to have a repository that's no longer available as a apt-get source.   I'm just wondering if this downtime is temporary or permanent, and what i can do to get the following command to work.

`sudo apt-get install enlightenment`

UPDATE:  as codeLes has indicated, there are additional repositories I need to add to my sources list, but the ones indicated are no longer around.  looking for alternatives.  thx.

Thanks,
Roy

Comment: I added comments to my answer below, don't want to reproduce them here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package is `e16` not `enlightenment`. It is available in the `universe` repository.

```
$ apt-cache show e16
Package: e16
Priority: optional
Section: universe/x11
Installed-Size: 928
Maintainer: Ubuntu MOTU Developers <ubuntu-motu@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Laurence J. Lane <ljlane@debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Version: 0.16.8.15-1
Provides: x-window-manager
Depends: e16-data (= 0.16.8.15-1), libaudiofile0 (>= 0.2.3-4), libc6 (>= 2.4), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.1.1), libesd-alsa0 (>= 0.2.35) | libesd0 (>= 0.2.35), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0), libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0), libimlib2 (>= 1.4.0), libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0), libsm6, libx11-6, libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1), libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1), libxext6, libxfixes3 (>= 1:4.0.1), libxft2 (>> 2.1.1), libxinerama1, libxrandr2 (>= 2:1.2.99.2), libxrender1, libxxf86vm1
Recommends: esound, menu
Suggests: eterm | x-terminal-emulator, e16keyedit, e16menuedit2
Conflicts: enlightenment (<< 1:0.16.8), menu (<< 2.0)
Filename: pool/universe/e/e16/e16_0.16.8.15-1_i386.deb
Size: 425486
MD5sum: b601de545fa92e14b0413c175eeabe7b
SHA1: 367da71126c2f7a0e2497a4fe6bdd9a1b3a8a42f
SHA256: 9af42811ef11208790ff470f04267b7cd5a133c41c238d6cd611e300c061093d
Description: the Enlightenment Window Manager DR16
 e16 is a window manager for the X Window System that is designed
 to be powerful, extensible, configurable and pretty darned good
 looking! It is one of the more graphically intense window managers.
 .
 e16 goes beyond managing windows by providing a useful and
 appealing graphical shell from which to work. It is open in design
 and instead of dictating a policy, allows the user to define their
 own policy, down to every last detail.
Homepage: http://www.enlightenment.org/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

You can also download deb packages directly from the [Enlightenment download page](http://www.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=download&l=en). As e17 isn't officially released, it isn't packaged yet for debian/ubuntu.

As an aside, you might open a ticket in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu) to have the package maintainer create a dependency / alias package, `enlightenment`.

Comment: Thanks! i'll pass on the luanchpad request, i'm sure the e team would like to reserve enlightenment keyword for e17 when they get it released (in 2050 lol)

Answer (score 1):

Having had issues trying to install e16 on Ubuntu 12.10, I thought I'd throw in an answer here rather than ask/answer my own for future reference. Note: This is specifically for getting e16 **instead of** e17, the latter of which is in main.

Lucid appears to be the last ubuntu repository that contains e16, having been replaced by e17 as of Oneiric, as can been seen by its absence in [this search query](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=oneiric&section=all&arch=any&keywords=e16&searchon=names).

However, it is possible to install from the old repositories by adding the following lines to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then running `sudo apt-get update`

```
## Adding Lucid repository in order to obtain e16
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted

deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe
deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
```

Afterwards, getting e16 is simply `sudo apt-get install e16`

Main is needed for certain e16 dependencies. I'm not sure if there are any downsides to including old repositories, but this gets e16 working right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-enlightenment-on-ubuntu-linux/) from the Hot-To Geek says:

> You will want to make sure that you have selected the alternate install repositories.

and provides a link to that as well.

Comment: yes i found that article on google too.  That specific article does not name specific repositories which contain enlightenment, only links to an article which generically indicates how to add additional sources to apt-get.   Those additional sources bundled with ubuntu do not have enlightenment.   There are specific repositories for e, and those mentioned in other articles are not around.   So i'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: do you have the universe repos checked?

Comment: and I think there may be a check box for 3rd party software/repos as well. make sure you refresh your repos when you check them too

Comment: I'm at work using windows, so I can't tinker with it myself at the moment.

Comment: yea, i had universe checked, but i was checking for enlightenment, not e16

Comment: glad to add to the conversation!

Answer (score 0):

google enlightenment and ppa (personal package archive?)

https://launchpad.net/~e17-packaging/+archive/ppa

Go there, do what they say, I would expect